# How to get product image watermark url?

Tags: magento2, watermark

I have uploaded an image on website level at ***Content => Design => Configuration***.

When I look into `core_config_data` table, path of this image is saved against column `design/watermark/small_image_image` with `scope_id` 2.

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    )
    {
    ....
     $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
     $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    public function getWatermarkSmallImage() {
       $image_url = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('design/watermark/small_image_image', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);

            var_dump($image_url);
    }
```

it prints null. Though when I use below code, it gives `string(18) "websites/2/red.jpg"`

```
$image_url = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('design/watermark/small_image_image', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE, 2);
```

How I can get complete url of this image which can be used with src tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get media url for your image src, so please add below function in your code to get media url

```
 public function getMediaUrl(){
       return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    }
```

So your final code is as per below

```
public function getWatermarkSmallImage() {
       $image_url = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('design/watermark/small_image_image', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
       $finalImageUrl = $this->getMediaUrl().$image_url;
            var_dump($finalImageUrl);
    }
```

Please check and let me know if any question.